# Extremally disconnected without Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, separation-axioms

In Theorem [T000045 of pi-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000045), a proof is given to defend the assertion from [Counterexamples in Topology](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-6290-9) that all [Extremally disconnected](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000049) ($T_2$ where the closure of open is open) spaces are [Totally separated](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000048) (for every two points there is a disconnection of the entire space that separates them). A current pull request to pi-Base removes the $T_2$ requirement for the extremally disconnected property; however, does T45 still hold without such an assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that the Hausdorff assumption is needed to show that extremally disconnected implies totally separated.

If we take *extremally disconnected* to mean the closure of any open set is open (without Hausdorff), then the following hold.

(1) Any [hyperconnected space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space) is extremally disconnected.  (Reason: any nonempty open set $U\subseteq X$ is dense in $X$, so its closure is the whole space, which is open.)

(2) Any space that is at the same time extremally disconnected and connected is hyperconnected.  (Reason: Any nonempty open set $U\subseteq X$ has a nonempty clopen closure.  Since the space is connected, that closure must be the whole space, that is, $U$ is dense in $X$.)

Answer (score 2):

Some additional assumption is required for this to work. For example, a two-point indiscrete space has the property that the closure of open is open, but is connected. A [particular point topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000009) provides a connected $T_0$ example: the closure of any non-empty open set is the whole space (and thus is open).

In fact, the [countable complement topology on the real numbers](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000017) is a $T_1$ (in fact, [strongly KC](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000103)) not $T_2$ space. This space is connected, and the closure of the any non-empty open set is the whole space (and thus is open).